# Building a skills mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, my brain is stuck and I can not find a way to accomplish what I want, so I am seeking your help please.

I have a simple form consists of:

- username `[input = "text"]`
- email `[input = "text"]`
- password `[input = "text"]`
- skills `[label]`

  - Swimming `[input = "checkbox"]`
  - Diving `[input = "checkbox"]`
  - Fishing `[input = "checkbox"]`
  - etc `[input = "checkbox"]`
  - etc `[input = "checkbox"]`
  - etc `[input = "checkbox"]`

the skills list is as long as you can imagine.

Now, I've created a db with two tables

Table 1: `[users]`

- userId
- userName
- userEmail
- userPassword

Table 2: `[skills]` *this table is a reference table*

- skillId
- skillName

Now, I wonder how can save the user skills and where?

One of the solutions I thought about was creating a 3rd table

Table 3: `[usersSkills]`

- id
- userId
- skillId

but the problem is I don't know -*and I couldn't figure out*- how to save the user skills in this table during the form process! **while the user doesn't have an ID yet**.

IS what I am doing is right? or is there a better approach?

I really appreciate your detailed help.

P.S.1: The form and the process are done in the same page. `register.php` and I am using `mySQLi`

**UPDATE**

Here is what I've done in the page:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" name="frmInput">

    Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="30"><br />
    Skills:
        <ul>
            <li>Skill 1: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="1" /></li>
            <li>Skill 2: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="2" /></li>
            <li>Skill 3: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="3" /></li>
            <li>Skill 4: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="4" /></li>
            <li>Skill 5: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="5" /></li>
        </ul>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ('$username')";
        $run    = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if($run)
        {
            $user_id = mysqli_insert_id();
            foreach ($_POST['skills'] as $skill)
            {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `users_skills` (`user_id`,`Skill_id`) VALUES ({$user_id},{$skill})";
                $run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

**UPDATE: Working now fine :)**

*This is the working code, I am posting it for future reference in case someone needs a tip, PLEASE be aware that this code is not a complete nor safe code, it is only for help and to show you the direction.*

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" name="frmInput">

    Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="30"><br />
    Skills:
        <ul>
            <li>Skill 1: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="1" /></li>
            <li>Skill 2: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="2" /></li>
            <li>Skill 3: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="3" /></li>
            <li>Skill 4: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="4" /></li>
            <li>Skill 5: <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="5" /></li>
        </ul>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ('$username')";
        $run    = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if($run == true)
        {
            $user_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            // echo $user_id;
            foreach($_POST['skills'] as $skill)
            {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `users_skills` (`user_id`,`Skill_id`) VALUES ({$user_id},{$skill})";
                $run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Thanks for all your help...

Comment: Yes the 3rd table idea is good and optimized. So can do first by adding the in user table, get the last inserted id and then save the data in the 3rd table with the last inserted id and skill id

Comment: You don't need a surrogate key in `usersSkills`. A composite key of `userId, skillId` will suffice.

Comment: @Kermit , by surrogate key you mean the `id column` in the 3rd table?

Comment: You should consider populating the skills checkboxes via a DB query against your skills table, you would then use the id from that table as the `value` in the input.  Without this, you don't have a way to reliably tie the skill listed in the form to the skill in the database.  This would also allow you to add skills simply by adding a row to the database (no HTML changes necessary).

Comment: @MikeBrant , yes you're 100% right but that was for example only. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you do not save while the user does not have an id. First you insert the user, get it's and then insert skills.

Your HTML should look like this:

```
... user data ...
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="1" /> Skill 1
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="2" /> Skill 2
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="3" /> Skill 3
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="4" /> Skill 4
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="5" /> Skill 5
```

And then in PHP you do something like this:

```
if (query("INSERT INTO users ...")) {
  $user_id = insert_id(); //with mysql it's mysqli_insert_id(), depeneds what you use to insert
  foreach ($_POST["skills"] as $skill) {
    //escape $skill with mysqli escape, or use as parameter
    query("INSERT INTO skills (user,skill) values ({$user},{$skill})");
  }
}
```

Obviously, you need to adapt this to suit your case, but I hope this gets your thoughts in right direction.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm trying yr code but getting this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)`

Answer (score 1):

First save the user, grab the last inserted id, and then save the skills. Can't make it harder then that ;)

If you're using mysqli you can use the [`$insert_id` property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to retrieve the last inserted id. Otherwise just execute this select query (see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for more info)

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```